# Using #{principal} in @Query leads to "Property or field 'principal' cannot be found on null"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Following [the official guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/data.html), Spring crashes with `Property or field 'principal' cannot be found on null` upon adding this @Query to a repo:

```
@Query("select count(e) from #{#entityName} e where e.user_id = #{principal?.id}")
```

To me, this seems like a circular dependency problem: in my case, the UserDetailsServiceImpl needs a JpaRepository. Generating this repo, Spring tries evaluating the @Query which itself relies on the security configuration (`SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` bean). The security configuration depends on the UserDetailsService. And. So. On.

I tried different ways to escape this (@DependsOn, removing @EnableJpaRepository, moving configs around) but didn't succeed. Since I'm pretty new to Spring, I think I'm doing something really stupid, so I'm asking you:

Is this constellation - Spring Security Data integration with a UserDetailsService depending on a JpaRepo - possible at all, and what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And stupid it is: I forgot the question mark denotating the query parameter.

@Query("select count(e) from #{#entityName} e where e.user_id = **?**#{principal?.id}")